# ASP Repeater with mutliple <ItemTemplate> tags

Tags: asp.net, xaml, repeater, itemtemplate

Very new to ASP.NET. We have a page which displays a list of things, but we want to add different options for how to display the list (as tiles with thumbnails, as text lists, etc). Our code basically follows this format:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater">
    <ItemTemplate>
        // HTML for Thumbnail-tile view
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

We've added radio boxes to select either the list view or the tile view, but I need to find a way to format the `<ItemTemplate>` tags differently depending on which one is selected, but I'm struggling. Things I've tried:

1. Separate Repeaters

This has so far been the most successful, but it *seems* like a messy solution, and will require refactoring a bit of code. I want to make sure there are no better options before committing to it. Basically I have two repeaters with their respective `<ItemTemplate>` fields.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1>
    <ItemTemplate>
        // HTML for Thumbnail-tile view
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater2>
    <ItemTemplate>
        // HTML for List view
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The page calls sets the DataSource and calls DataBind() on the default repeater on page load, and a handler for each radio button will flush one, and fill the other for their respective lists. Two repeaters seems like overkill, and to make it work seamlessly we'll need to refactor it a little.

2. Placeholders

Basically formatting the code thus:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="???"></asp:Placeholder>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Generate the code for the template in the code behind depending on our radio buttons, and just send that to the client. Elegant. Only problem is the ID of the placeholder can't be a duplicate, and in a repeater that's exactly what it's going to be.

3. Hide the one we're not using

Basically we put the code for both

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="ListView" style="display: block"> // HTML for List view</div>
        <div class="TileView" style="display: none">> // HTML for Thumbnail-Tile view </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And the radio button event handler will just update the css on the appropriate div. This impacts performance, as we are still loading the thumbnails, urls, and other info for the hidden list. We want to avoid all unnecessary overhead for this project, so this is going to be out of the question.

Have I missed any other ways to approach this problem? Like I said, I'm pretty new to ASP.NET, so I'm not confident I've considered all the potential functionality. I've been reading about the ItemTemplateSelector property, but I cant figure out how to go about using it.

Comment: I think you are on right track. May be you can use asp panel within item template. You will set two panels, one for listview and other for tile view. And you can hide/show them based on selection.

Comment: If I use a panel, wont I have to give it an ID to be able to access it from the code behind? If it's in a repeater, will it have the same problem as my placeholder idea?

Comment: Well you can access panels in code behind within item databound event

Comment: Ok so it would have a duplicate ID, but there wouldnt be any issues since I'm not accessing it using that ID?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use CSS to get the data to flow how you want.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .list-view {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .thumbnail-view {
        width: 25%;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panelContent">
            // Your content
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Based on the selection of the RadioButtonList, just alternate between the two CSS classes. Whenever the Repeater binds its data, find the Panel in the row and set the CSS class to whatever it needs to be.

```cs
protected void repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Panel panelContent = (Panel)e.Item.FindControl("panelContent");
        if (myRadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "list")
        {
            panelContent.CssClass = "list-view";
        }
        else if (myRadioButtonList.SelectedValue == "thumbnail")
        {
            panelContent.CssClass = "thumbnail-view";
        }
    }
}
```

The downside to this solution would be needing to be familiar enough with CSS. If you aren't, I strongly recommend getting familiar with it. Especially if you are going to be continuing with web development.

Other than that though, I would probably prefer your first option. I like the idea of separating them into two repeaters and only using the one you need. This makes it easy to work with in the future. If you need to make changes to one repeater, you just do it right there on the .aspx page.

Comment: Isnt this similar to my show/hide divs solution? Would the page still be loading the image resources, etc, just not showing them?

Comment: Definitely similar but much more efficient. Your solution, as I understand it, would do double work. It would create all the controls for the list view and then create all the controls for the thumbnail view as well, every time, even when they aren't needed. My solution would use the existing controls and just simply toggle how they look. Nothing would need to be hidden.